# Which is better practice for this if elif… else statement?

Tags: python, comparative-review

If below piece of code has to be restructured to use but one single if-elif block, which is better? 1. or 2.?

> [image: python code to categorise small naturals]

```
A = int(input("Enter an integer(1~30): "))
```

1. 

```
if A % 6 == 0:
    print("A is even")
    print("A is even and a multiple of 6 (6, 12, 18, 24, 30).")
elif A % 10 == 0:
    print("A is even")
    print("A is even and a multiple of 10 (10, 20).")
elif A % 2 == 0:
    print("A is even")
    print("A is even and a number out of 2, 4, 8, 14, 16, 22, 26, 28.")
elif A % 3 == 0:
    print("A is odd")
    print("A is odd and a multiple of 3 (3, 9, 15, 21, 27).")
else:
    print("A is odd")
    print("A is 1 or a number out of 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29.")
```

2. 

```
if A % 2 == 0 and A % 3 == 0:
    print("A is even")
    print("A is even and a multiple of 6 (6, 12, 18, 24, 30).")
elif A % 2 == 0 and A % 5 == 0:
    print("A is even")
    print("A is even and a multiple of 10 (10, 20).")
elif A % 2 == 0 and A % 3 != 0 and A % 5 != 0:
    print("A is even")
    print("A is even and a number out of 2, 4, 8, 14, 16, 22, 26, 28.")
elif A % 2 != 0 and A % 3 == 0:
    print("A is odd")
    print("A is odd and a multiple of 3 (3, 9, 15, 21, 27).")
else:
    print("A is odd")
    print("A is 1 or a number out of 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29.")
```

This is part of a question in a school assignment and the problem is to reformat some code into the structure of

```
if
    …
elif
    …
elif
    …
else
    …
```

There are obviously better structures to avoid multiplicating `print("A is even")` but the question is to format it in the structure above.

So if the two above are the only options which is better and why?

Comment: It seems like the real question is "what logic is best to use for finding multiples of an input number?" because the `if-else` statements are used the same, the logic is different. If you have the same 'mass' of code for both scenarios, using the one that is simpler (without `and`s and `or`s) would be more readable in most cases.

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Anyway the second snippet contains superfluous checks and is quite harder to ready. It may be just my opinion though. In general your question is going to generate opinion based answers which is yet another reason to close this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited  the question to add some context. These are answers to a problem in a school assignment and is not part of a bigger project. The problem is to simply reformat a simple piece of code into the structure I mentioned.

Comment: Note that the enumeration for `% 5 == 0` does not mention 30, and "the else" presents `1` as an alternative to `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important fact first: You are required to refactor a reasonable piece of code into an evil one. An if-elif-else-rake is very seldom the best solution. That said I'll try to give two general rules.

---

When testing for `"a multiple of 6 (6, 12, 18, 24, 30)"`

```
if A % 6 == 0:
```

is the more readable and less error prone solution compared to

```
if A % 2 == 0 and A % 3 == 0:
```

Writing good code is not about showing off math knowledge.

---

When we do an if-elif-else rake we do not do

```
if a:
    ...
elif not a and b:
    ...
elif not a and not b and c:
    ...
elif not a and not b and not c and d:
    ...
```

we do

```
if a:
    ...
elif b:
    ...
elif c:
    ...
elif d:
    ...
```

The `not` conditions are implicitly there.
Again the reason is readability, simplicity and thus less probability of errors. Maintainability counts, think of inserting a clause later. It is also avoiding multiple evaluation of tests.

---

So your first code example is a little less evil as there is no code duplication and better readability.

Comment: `your first code example is a little less evil as there is no code duplication` would be the pixel raster interpretation, not alternative `1.`.

Answer (score 2):

The following is better IMO. Duplicated "`A is odd`" / "`A is even`" strings are omitted from the output. They could be added if required.

```
if A % 2 == 0:
    if A % 6 == 0:
        msg = "a multiple of 6 (6, 12, 18, 24, 30)"
    elif A % 10 == 0:
        msg = "a multiple of 10 (10, 20)"
    else:
        msg = "a number out of 2, 4, 8, 14, 16, 22, 26, 28"
    print(f"A is even and {msg}.")
else:
    if A % 3 == 0:
        msg = "a multiple of 3 (3, 9, 15, 21, 27)"
    else:
        msg = "a number out of 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29"
    print(f"A is odd and {msg}.")
```

As for which one of the two versions of the provided code is better, I agree with @stefan's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to know which is better out of the two. I edited my question to add some context.

Comment: (Check input `1`. (in the original))

Comment: @greybeard I changed the output string from "A is 1 or a number out of 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29." to "A is odd and a number out of ... ."  because I thought it was a typo. The second part of the sentence already included `1` so there was no point to repeat it in the first part. Now more context have been added to the question so we can see the typo is from the original version of the code.

Comment: @anonymous I agree with stefan's answer on that question.